# nose2 Execute Tests from Multiple Classes in a Single Module

Tags: testcase, nose2

I have a module with multiple Classes in it. For example, module tests.py:

```
class Test_method_1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1_1(self):
        # test steps
        assert True

    def test_1_2(self):
        # test steps
        assert False

class Test_method_2(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_2_1(self):
        # test steps
        assert True

    def test_2_2(self):
        # test steps
        assert False
```

When I execute:
`nose2` tests

`nose2` will only execute the tests in class Test_method_1. If I execute:

```
nose2 tests.Test_method_2
```

`nose2` executes the tests in `Test_method2`. How do I get `nose2` to execute all of the tests in both classes?